# Open App Store while connected to BrowserMob proxy

Tags: ios, proxy, app-store, browsermob

I'm using BrowserMob proxy to monitor iOS device network data - HTTP and HTTPS requests.
The problem is that when I try to open App Store on the device, the requests are blocked by App Store (because of SSL pinning).
I've encountered this issue while using Charles proxy as well, but in Charles there is an option to disable SSL proxying for specific urls (such as iTunes). I wonder if there is an option to do this on BrowserMob as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

following...
same as me
still not find a solution other that change from mitm (homebrew) proxy to a different one

Comment: this looks like a comment rather than an answer, please provide relevant supporting information and codes to make it a meaningful answer.